# What happens when two processes write to same portion of a mmaped file?

Tags: c, linux, posix, mmap

I am writing a C program that makes use of `mmap` system call, running on Linux 3.12 64-bit.

If I have two processes mmaping the same region of a disk file with read/write access, and then modify the region content from both processes at the same time...

- Can one process see (read) changed data made by the other process, before or after msync?
- If update can be seen by the other process - is there a happens-before guarantee made by Linux mmap implementation?

Comment: A race condition and eventually Undefined behavior.You need to synchronize the access to the memory mapped file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's one of the purposes of memory mapping: as a form of "instantaneous IPC".

You must set the MAP_SHARED flag:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

If you wish to use shared memory for this purpose, I would consider the shminit()/shmat() APIs instead:

- http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat

Suggestion: check out Beej's Guide to *nix Interprocess Communication:

- http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/

And no, if you use the raw mmap() APIs, there's no "before/after guarantee", and you must use some kind of locking (e.g. semaphores) if you wish to read/write data concurrently.

Also, from [Understanding Memory Mapping](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.genprogc%2Fdoc%2Fgenprogc%2Funderstanding_mem_mapping.htm):

> Both the mmap and shmat services provide the capability for multiple
>   processes to map the same region of an object such that they share
>   addressability to that object. However, the mmap subroutine extends
>   this capability beyond that provided by the shmat subroutine by
>   allowing a relatively unlimited number of such mappings to be
>   established. While this capability increases the number of mappings
>   supported per file object or memory segment, it can prove inefficient
>   for applications in which many processes map the same file data into
>   their address space.
>
> The mmap subroutine provides a unique object address for each process
>   that maps to an object. The software accomplishes this by providing
>   each process with a unique virtual address, known as an alias. The
>   shmat subroutine allows processes to share the addresses of the mapped
>   objects.

The above is true of any *nix variant, including both Linux and AIX.