# Linux: What happens when the underlying memory mapped file is changed?

Tags: linux

Suppose my app maps fileA, and fileA is changed by another process. The next time my app attempts to read from fileA, will it see the updated data?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811434/what-happens-when-two-processes-write-to-same-portion-of-a-mmaped-file

Answer (score 3):

If you used a shared map, yes.

If you used a private map, no.